# RegEx Exclude a specific string even if it meets group criteria

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am not sure how to explain it in a title so an example will be better.

I am trying to parse phone numbers and general number and I want my phone numbers to not be taken into consideration by my expression.

My text is the following:

My phone numbers are +4405490198756 | 05490198756 | 05 49 01 98 756 and my numbers are 4123-0123-6123-7123 | 4123512361237123 | 4123 5123 6123 7123

My expression is `(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|\b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b)`

Basically, I am taking everything starting by 4 with 12 or 15 characters between 0 and 9 after and I don't consider spaces nor '-'.

My phone number +4405490198756 is included in the result of this regex at least the numeric part since it answers the expression.
I don't want it to be included in the results.

I tried to play with `\b^[+]\d{13,16}\b` and everything I could think about around that but nothing worked.

Any idea on I should proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are writing it in JS, [`(?:^|[^\d+])(4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/8p9hQQ/1) and grab Group 1. Else, `(?<![\d+])(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16})\b` might do ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8p9hQQ/2/)).

Comment: It's probably easier to filter out your number from the result in the application code rather than trying to do this in the regexp itself.

Comment: It's often easy to get caught up in trying to write one RegEx that does everything you need to. Sometimes this is overly complicated, and this is a good example. Rather than trying to exclude one specific match from a pattern here. Match the phone number patterns first, then in a second expression, exclude your phone number.

Comment: Why did you put the entire regex into a non-capturing group `(?:xxx)`?